# Django not cleaning certain form fields

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-forms

So my form is the following:

```
class Uploaded_Cisco_YML_Configs(forms.Form):
    uploaded_configs = forms.FileField()
    goto_model = forms.TextInput()
    interfaces_migrate = forms.Textarea()
```

The issue I'm having is that the goto_model and interfaces_migrate form fields are defined in the form.data dictionary however their not in the form.cleaned_data so I'm unable to access them properly. Is there any reason why this might be happening?.

The HTML is below

```
            <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input id="uploaded_configs" name="uploaded_configs" type="file" multiple/>
        <br>
        New Model:<br>
        <input type="text" name="goto_model">
        <br>Interfaces to Migrate:
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="interfaces_migrate">
        <input type="submit" value="Run Script"/>
         </form>
```

And the views.py is below

```
form = Uploaded_Cisco_YML_Configs(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            rebuild_args = []
            if form.goto_model is not None:
                print("#"*10)
                print(str(form.data))
                print(str(form.cleaned_data))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TextInput and Textarea are not form fields, they are widgets. You need to define a field and then set the widget argument, if necessary.

```
class Uploaded_Cisco_YML_Configs(forms.Form):
    uploaded_configs = forms.FileField()
    goto_model = forms.CharField()
    interfaces_migrate = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea())
```

(You don't need to set the widget for `goto_model` as TextInput is the default for a CharField.)

Note that `if form.goto_model is not None` will never be false, because it refers to the *field definition* and not the value; you would need to access `form.cleaned_data['goto_model']`, but even that is pointless because the field is required and therefore the form will not be valid if it is empty.